# Tensorflow: python tf.gradients equivalent in C++

Tags: tensorflow

What is the equivalent of Python function `tf.gradients(loss, [var])` in C++? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent function in C++ is [`tensorflow::AddSymbolicGradients()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1975cd1e9d539e75a1b85b56f16448c91ef88d90/tensorflow/core/graph/gradients.h#L50). You will need to obtain a `tensorflow::Graph` object representing your graph to use this function. However, adding gradients in C++ is **still experimental**, so beware that this function signature is subject to change.